# registration/login on checkout and on website

Tags: authentication, registration, shopping-cart, webshop

I'm creating a webshop.
On index.php, I have a link that goes to registration and loginform.
When I add a product to my shopping cart, I check if the user is already logged in. If not, the user has to register. 
How can I use the same registration form, and check if the user comes from the page shopping cart, or from the index (or another page)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies for that. You need to store cookies and then restore it when login page is revisited.